# Not able to create site policy for closing a site collection (Team site)

Tags: sharepoint-online, 2013, 2010, office-365

I am trying to close the site collection using site policies.

I activated the site policy feature and when I clicked on the Site Policies to create a new one, it gave me a generic error message

> Sorry, a problem has occurred

Are there any other features we need to activate/deactivate to make the site policies work?

The site is a team site and I am able to create site policies in other team sites. Not sure what I am missing

Comment: Is this a communication or team site?

Comment: It is a team site @CallumCrowley

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the site policy function, no other functions need to be activated.

Please check ULS logs or event logs for any clues.

As a workaround, we could use powershell to make the site collection read only:

```
Set-SPSite -Identity "SiteCollection" -LockState "No access"
```

More information for your reference:

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/sites/manage-the-lock-status-for-site-collections

http://laurentschoenaers.be/2020/04/24/sharepoint-online-lockunlock-your-site/

Comment: great, thanks for the tip
so with this we can even make a sub site read only?

Comment: If it helps you, you can mark the reply as an answer.